# How do I get MSBuild Message task to display a property?

Tags: msbuild

According to [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yy0yx8d.aspx), the MSBuild Message task should be able to output the contents of a property to the console.

This can be demonstrated quite simply with the following line:

```
<Message Text=" MSBuildProjectDirectory  = $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
```

When I run the above line as part of a build target I get something like this:

```
[exec]    MSBuildProjectDirectory  = .../somefolderpath
```

Within my build scripts I have a property that defines the path to an executable file.  It's definition looks something like this:

```
<MyDir Condition="'$(MyDir)' == ''">somepath</MyDir>
<MyEXE Condition="'$(MyEXE)' == ''">$(MyDir)\somefile.exe</MyEXE>
```

I would like to print out the content of the $(MyEXE).
My expectation was that this would work:

```
<Message Text=" MyEXE= $(MyEXE)" />
```

...but it doesn't.  In fact, it behaves as though the line wasn't there at all.

For the following:

```
<Message Text="TEMP START"/>
<Message Text=" MSBuildProjectDirectory  = $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />

<Message Text='dollar1 "$(MyEXE)"'/>
<Message Text="dollar2 '$(MyEXE)'"/>
<Message Text='dollar3 $(MyEXE)'/>
<Message Text="dollar4 $(MyEXE)"/>

<Message Text='at1 "@(MyEXE)"'/>
<Message Text="at2 '@(MyEXE)'"/>
<Message Text='at3 @(MyEXE)'/>
<Message Text="at4 @(MyEXE)"/>

<Exec Command='echo "$(MyEXE)"' />
<Exec Command='echo FOO' />

<Message Text="TEMP END"/>
```

...I get the following output:

```
[exec]   TEMP START
[exec]    MSBuildProjectDirectory  = .../somepath
[exec]   at1 ""
[exec]   at2 ''
[exec]   at3
[exec]   at4
[exec]   echo FOO
[exec]   FOO
[exec]   TEMP END
```

The very next line is

```
<Exec Command='"$(MyEXE)" /someparameter' />
```

...which executes the exe successfully, so it clearly contains a value.

It's worth noting that my use of @(MyEXE) is entirely my ignorance clutching at straws.

Does anyone know how I print the content of $(MyEXE) to the console?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I get correct output here (though without the '[exec]' part, where does that come from?) Then again, what you show isn't valid msbuild since it's missing a bunch of tags (PropertyGroup/Target). I added those where I assume you have them as well, but I cannot be sure.. Better show the complete code you are using, and how you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, MSBuild.exe is being called from an [ant exec task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).  If this step is removed and MSBuild called directly from the command line, the problem goes away.

Update 2017.02.08:
Investigating further, I have found that our ant build scripts parse the console output from msbuild to 'helpfully' remove 'unwanted' content using an array of regex-based string replacement.

As an aside, the '[exec]' at the beginning of the output that I posted in the question is added by ant.